# Will I be affected by the travel ban Europe to USA (Connecting flight)

Tags: usa, europe, visa-bans

Will I be able to get home to Canada?

My flight is on March 18th from Delhi to Frankfurt Germany to Seattle to Vancouver (where we live).

The layover is 3 hours in Germany and 2 in Seattle.

The DHS stated "this does not apply to legal permanent residents, (generally) immediate family members of US citizens, and other individuals who are identified in the proclamation"

I am not sure what they mean by immediate family but my mom's sister is an American citizen that lives by Seattle, would this help us at all?

Also would it matter since we just have connecting flights in the USA and Germany?

I have tried to call Flight Network and Lufthansa but they both have pre-recorded messages saying call us later.

Comment: Usually, "immediate family" is limited to spouses, parents, and children.

Comment: @GregHewgill Yea that's what I thought, I think they won't let us in even though we're just connecting flights both ways. And there's a high chance the FRA to SEA flight will just get canceled

Comment: Correct. The infection risk from you being inside an airport terminal used concurrently or shortly (meaning days, not minutes) prior by infected passengers and staff is too great. Best you seek alternate routing, like through Japan or Singapore.

Comment: Or the UK, which hasn't been included in the ban.

Comment: @Michael Hampton Yet...

Comment: [*The acting DHS secretary, Chad Wolf, said that guidance on the travel suspension would come within the next two days.*](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2020/mar/11/coronavirus-outbreak-us-trump-latest).  Sounds like you'll need to wait a couple of days to see if that guidance contains details for connecting travel.

Comment: Lufthansa flights from Frankfurt to Seattle are now cancelled, starting March 14th. Even if you are allowed to fly to the US, you’ll have to be rebooked in a new itinerary.